# QML Material Design colors aren't accurate

Tags: c++, qml, material-design, qt5.7, qtquickcontrols2

I'm trying to use the Purple and other colors specified on [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-material.html) page but the colors aren't displaying accurately.
This is the image of Purple color being displayed on my device as well as linux:

[image]

Here are the relevant code snippets from the default Hello World app:
.pro file:

```
QT += qml quick quickcontrols2
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QQuickStyle>
```

In `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`
    `QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");`

main.qml:

```
Material.theme: Material.Dark
Material.accent: Material.Purple
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Material Design specs are a bit inconsistent about this. In the sticker sheet, all buttons are using such lighter shade in the dark theme, whereas elsewhere in the specs they are mostly using the same darker shade than in the light theme. We're considering switching it back, but meanwhile, here's a temporary workaround using `Material.color()`:

```
Material.theme: Material.Dark
Material.accent: Material.color(Material.Purple)
```

- [QTBUG-54269](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54269): Material colors don't work as documented